# Is an e-mail address a URI?

Tags: uri, email

I've tried to figure out whether the format of an e-mail address can be said to comply with the definition of a URI or not, but I've found no explicit confirmation of this so far. I hope someone can provide me with some insight here. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, but with "mailto:" prefix.

A URI has this form:

```
<scheme>:<scheme-specific-part>
```

The `<scheme>` is "mailto", the `<scheme-specific-part>` is the address.

For example:

```
mailto:max@provider.com
```

is a valid URI.

Comment: So, without the `mailto:` scheme, an email address cannot be considered a URI?

Answer (score 18):

Per [**RFC 3986**](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

> A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is
>   a compact sequence of characters that
>   identifies an abstract or physical
>   resource.

The basic syntax components as defined by the RFC:

```
The generic URI syntax consists of a hierarchical sequence of
components referred to as the scheme, authority, path, query, and
fragment.

  URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]

  hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
              / path-absolute
              / path-rootless
              / path-empty
```

So - an e-mail address is not a URI. However `mailto:you@server.com` is a valid URI.

Answer (score 5):

An e-mail address on it's own - foo@bar.com - I'd say no.
A link to an e-mail address - mailto:foo@bar.com - I'd say yes.

Comment: A URI doesn't need to include the scheme part (`mailto`) to be valid.

Comment: @Massimo Fazzolari - yes, you are correct - I was mistaken - the ABNF for RFC 3986 requires a scheme.

Answer (score 2):

yes when used with "mailto" scheme, look here:
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

1.3. Example URI

The following examples illustrate URI that are in common use.

mailto:mduerst@ifi.unizh.ch
      -- mailto scheme for electronic mail addresses

Comment: section 1.3 of the rfc has an email example

Comment: but only with the "mailto" qualifier.  Think of it this way, HREF's takes URIs.

Comment: @Stephen Wrighton - a URI doesn't need to include the scheme part (`mailto`) to be valid.

Comment: @McDowell: Cite? RFC 3986 appears to disagree.

Comment: @Andrew Aylett - yes, you are correct - I was mistaken - the ABNF clearly requires a scheme.

Answer (score 2):

If all URL's are URI's then all soandso@somwhere.com address are URIs because they are URLs

So I think an email address is a URI, if it has mailto: in front of it.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738

Answer (score 1):

I think it is, if it includes the "mailto:" schema reference in the address; otherwise not. But as it is only seen at html pages, in the most of cases the email address it self could not be considered a URI.

If you haven't checked before, take a look at [RFC3305 document](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3305.txt).

The official register of URI scheme names is maintained by IANA at http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.html

I hope it helps,
Carlos.