# What are the parsed components of a mailto URI

Tags: email, uri, language-lawyer, mailto

An e-mail address is a valid URI [when encoded using the `mailto` scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184740/is-an-e-mail-address-a-uri):

```
 mailto:user@example.com
```

(See [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068))

But how should that be parsed according to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3), the standard for *Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax*?

- Is the user name part of the e-mail address (`user` of `mailto:user@example.com`) the *user name* of the [*user info*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1) part?
- Is the host-name part of the e-mail address (`example.com` of `mailto:user@example.com`) the [*host* part](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2)?

Comment: I am answering my own question, [as is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite an e-mail address containing a user name and a host name, when encoded in a mailto URI, the e-mail address constitutes part of the *path* of the URI, and the user part and host part are considered empty. This is because the user, password (if it was present) and host would constitute the [*authority*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2) part of the URI, **which must be preceded by "`//`"**.

That is, if the 'mailto' URI scheme had mandated `mailto://user@example.com` rather than `mailto:user@example.com`, the parsing would be as expected. A 'mailto' is thus, [rather strangely, a URN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37645520/545127).